# Grunt-Includes Templating On Filename?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

My current Grunt implementation uses grunt-includes to wrap all of my pages in the header/footer code.  What I am looking for is a way to add dynamic bits to the header and footer to load CSS/JS as well as add classes to the body tag, but I need them to be based on the name of the file requesting the include during the grunt-includes task.

I could get everything done I needed to if I could simply get grunt-includes to pass the name of the requesting file into the included file.  In reading the documentation for grunt-includes I can see that there appears to be some kind of template for {{fileName}} and {{file}} but I can't seem to get these to work.

Just to clarify, what I am looking for is, when running grunt-includes via grunt, if a file named `myFile.html` has the line `include "global/myHeader.html"`, `myFile` or `myFile.html` gets passed into `global/myHeader.html` as it is concatenated onto `myFile.html`.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction here? I've been spinning my wheels for two days.

My includes function that I am currently using is as follows:

```
includes: {
    files: {
        src: ['sources/*.html'], // Source files
        dest: 'app', // Destination directory
        flatten: true,
        cwd: '.',
        options: {
            silent: true,
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The template setting goes in the options object of the files object.  This is the only place where `{{file}}` and `{{fileName}}` can be used.  This means if you wan't to "pass" these into the requested files you either have to put the entire string in the template (not recommended), or pass just the file name into a hidden tag and use JavaScript to handle whatever dynamics you needed.

I recommend using grunt template for this instead:
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template